# IActiveAware Interface in Prism

Tags: wpf, prism

Can someone shed some light on active aware interface is in Prism, how it helps delegate command.

Answer (score 1):

It's very similar in concept to my [`ActiveAwareCommand`](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/05/mvvm-infrastructure-activeawarecommand.html), and that blog post explains why this is necessary.